# Cucumber JVM for running cucumber features parallely

Tags: cucumber, jruby, cucumber-jvm

I have rails application and using cucumber features for testing. To speed up execution i am thinking to use Cucumber-JVM for parallel testing. Does it provide parallel testing of cucumber features and using JRuby ?

Answer (score 1):

[Cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) provided parallel execution as of v4.0.0. However, [Cucumber-jvm-JRuby](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-jruby)  was removed from the Cucumber-jvm project to it's own project, which may not (yet) offer parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

if you create few tasks with different db configuration and different features - it will working parallel and faster